# php with javascript timer - what happen when user leaves the page before the timer is zero

Tags: php, javascript, countdown

i have a game whene the user can win something.
as soon as he wins he has 60 seconds to fill in his adress name etcotherwise he lose his price and someone else can take it.
when he not fills in the adress in 60 seconds then he gets redirected to a sorry too late page and he lose his price.
when he fills in his adress he gets redirected to a confirmation page and can claim his price.

i made this with php and the counter is in javascript.
the javascript will do the redirect when time = 0

how can i controll that the user either goes to the confirmation page or to the soory to late page.
i'm wondering how i can be sure that the javascript countdown is really counted to zero even wehn the users leaves the page.

thanks a lot

Comment: A bot will easily win prizes by bypassing that timer. The server won't know if the timer was really completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try not to trust only javascript for this job, use php to write the time in the session or an database when the user gets the form to fill in his data - check the difference (with php) between this starting-time and the end-time when the user submits the form to the server
and show him the confirmation when diff<=1min or show him sorry-to-late when diff>1min

Comment: thanks roeb
how can i then make kind of o cron job to check if the user has filled in the form or if he left the page?

Comment: no cron job needed ... when you serve the form to the user, add a line to a database (id, starttime) and write the id in a hidden field in the form - when the form was submitted and is processed by the server it's time to calculate the difference between starttime and actual time

Answer (score 4):

You can't be sure - your users can easily modify your javascript to increase the time limit or even disable the timer completely.

The time limit should be validated on the server. I would suggest that when the time limit starts the server stores a row in the database storing which user it is and when the time limit started. When the user submits the server should check the database to see how much time has passed.

I also think that having just 60 seconds to fill in your address is rather harsh, but that's your decision.

Comment: thanks mark, but this is not the problem, because the user has allready won a price. he just has to enter his adress etc to get the price.

Comment: @oli - We may need a brief example from your source code to solve this.

Comment: @oli: If I "won" a prize on your site but only if I fill out my personal details within 60 seconds I would probably just ignore it, just like I ignore it when I'm told I'm the 1,000,000th visitor. If you want people to take your site seriously you need to make your site professional quality. Using client-side timers to determine whether to award prizes is not professional. Chancers are the only users that will find it interesting are bots and people who understand HTML / Javascript.

Comment: @ Steve
this is my javascript

Comment: <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
<!--

var Product_ID= "<?php echo $Product_ID; ?>";
var urlforward="xxxxx/toolate.php?item=" + Product_ID;

sek=60;
function countdown(){
sek--;

document.getElementById('clever_timer1').innerHTML='00:' + sek;


if(sek>0)setTimeout('countdown()',1000);
else parent.location.href=urlforward;
}
//-->


</SCRIPT>

Answer (score 0):

you could do this, use javascript for user interfase, and when user leaves a filed execute ajax call to php script and save data that he just entered in field. And real counting make in php, so when user submits final data u should also check if time expired in php.

I think this is good solution for your problem.

Comment: and how can i make a countdown in php?
could i check with ignore_user_abort if the script runs total or the users leaves before ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do this in Javascript, anybody can read your script and find where the prize page is.

Instead, run your timer with PHP using [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).  You can start when they see the "You Win" page.  It will run in the background, and won't depend on any user interaction.

Comment: thanks, but how can i check if the users hasn't leave the page? this is my real problem. what happen when the users is leaving the page during the countdown? can i start sometinh like a cron job ?